# PHP Parse error function.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Please guys I really need your help here.

I've tried to add some *PHP* code to `Appearance > Editor > functions.php` file, but when I delete what I entered I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/totconsu/public_html/wp-content/themes/shopkeeper/functions.php on line 1028

The code is:

```
function languages_top_bar(){
    $languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0&orderby=code');

    if(!empty($languages)) : ?>

       <div id="top_bar_language_list" class="topbar-language-switcher">

       <ul>
            <li class="menu-item-first"><a href="#"><?php echo ICL_LANGUAGE_NAME; ?></a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">

           <?php
            foreach($languages as $l) {
                echo '<li class="sub-menu-item">';
                if($l['country_flag_url']){
                    if(!$l['active']) echo '<a class="flag" href="'.$l['url'].'">';
                    echo '<img src="'.$l['country_flag_url'].'" height="12" alt="'.$l['language_code'].'" width="18" />';
                    if(!$l['active']) echo '</a>';
                }
                if(!$l['active']) echo '<a href="'.$l['url'].'">';
                echo icl_disp_language($l['native_name'], $l['translated_name']);
                if(!$l['active']) echo '</a>';
                echo '</li>';
            }

            echo '</ul></li>';
            ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo '</ul></div>'; 
}
```

Please I'm stuck... (

Comment: Can you show us line `1028`?

Comment: Tried copy all the functions.php file to text wrangler to see line 1028 but it it goes until 1026, I don't get it :(

Comment: i didint added that part, this was already in functions.php shopkeeper file.

Comment: just found line 1028 on cpanel: <?php

Comment: thats the only thing in the line, should i remove anything and try?

Comment: Guys just found the solution. For those with the same product, you have to the delete the code you added on cpanel functions.php file, because even you eliminated it on Appearance>Editor>Functions.php it is still added on the server. Thanks for the help War10ck

Comment: @Barmar Interesting. Learned something new. Ignore my previous. Thank you for the resource!